# CryptStringToBinary bug? Or do I not understand something?

Tags: windows, winapi, cryptoapi

It seems the value returned by `CryptStringToBinary()` in `pdwSkip` parameter is wrong.
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptstringtobinarya) says:

> `pdwSkip` - a pointer to a DWORD value that receives the number of
>   characters skipped to reach the beginning of the actual base64 or
>   hexadecimal strings.

```
char buf[100]={0};
DWORD bufSize=sizeof(buf);
DWORD skip=0, flags=0;
BOOL rv=CryptStringToBinary("\r\n\t c3Nzc3Nzcw==\r\n\t ",0,CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,
                            buf,&bufSize,&skip,&flags);
if(rv) {
  printf("skip=%u\n",skip);
}
```

The code prints:
skip=0
I expected it to be 4 because "the actual base64 string" is "c3Nzc3Nzcw==". And before it there are 4 characters.
I tested it on Windows 8.1 with latest updates.

Comment: Why do you expect the API to assume 4 bytes of header information when you tell it that there is no header? Put another way: Why do you expect `pdwSkip` to point at any other value than 0 after a successful call?

Comment: @IInspectable because the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptstringtobinarya) says _`pdwSkip` - a pointer to a DWORD value that receives the number of characters skipped to reach the beginning of the actual base64 or hexadecimal strings_. The actual base64 string starts with "c3N". And before it there are 4 characters

Comment: You should maybe clarify that in an edit to your question. It _is_ a bit confusing otherwise.

Comment: The doc does not state what the beginning of the actual base64 is. If you add the correct header, such as "-----BEGIN STUFF -----", you will find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `CRYPT_STRING_BASE64` in the third param - that means there are no headers.

If you pass `CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER` instead, the function will interpret your string as [PEM encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) data. PEM looks like this:

```
------ BEGIN STUFF --------------
AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCD
GGGGGGGGGGGaaaaaaaaaaaaasss666666
------ END STUFF---------
```

I'm not sure what exactly is the heuristic that the function uses to detect the header (probably a sequence of dashes, followed by some ASCII, followed by more dashes, then EOL), but `"\r\n\t "` is definitely not a reasonable header in a PEM encoded crypto object. Those are valid Base64 characters. **The docs make a reference to "certificate beginning and ending headers" - that's a very specific thing, the PEM header/footer lines.**

Not sure if the function is designed to quietly skip whitespace between Base64 characters, the docs are silent on that. That said, **quietly skipping whitespace is pretty much a requirement for any PEM friendly Base64 decoder**. PEM includes whitespace (the newlines) by design. But they definitely don't count that whitespace as a header. For one thing, whitespace in PEM occurs in the middle.

Comment: It's either a bug or the Microsoft documentation is very confusing. Because in the description of `pdwSkip` there is nothing about PEM headers. I consider _c3Nzc3Nzcw==_ the actual base64 string in my example and it starts after the 4th byte of the input string

Comment: The docs don't make a specific reference to PEM, but if you've been around certs for a while, "certificate beginning and ending headers" is clear enough. I agree, the docs could've been better. :)

Answer (score 1):

After you add the the beginning of the actual base64, you will receive the number of skipped characters.

Try this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib,"Crypt32.lib")

int main()
{
    LPCSTR szPemPublicKey =
        "\r\n\t "
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----"
        "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqRLhZXK29Xo5YdSoMdAe"
        "MHwDYAmThPSJzbQaBhVLCY1DTQr0JRkvd+0xfdwih97bWUXVpxuOgYH9hofIzZGP"    
        "-----END CERTIFICATE -----";
    BYTE derPrivateKey[2048];
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    DWORD bufSize = sizeof(buf);

    DWORD skip = 0, flags = 0;
    BOOL rv = CryptStringToBinary(szPemPublicKey, 0, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER,
        derPrivateKey, &bufSize, &skip, &flags);
    if (rv) {
        printf("skip=%u\n", skip);
    }
}
```

Debug:

[image]

Comment: @CITBL Hi, you can mark one of the answers that is useful to you to end this thread. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.